# Powering a constant current strip with a constant voltage supply

Tags: led, constant-current

I have an application where I have the following components installed.

277 Vac to 48 Vdc Constant Voltage Driver (MeanWell) -> 48 Vdc CV PWM dimming interface controlled by 0-10 V -> constant current strip (44-48 V and can be run at 40, 50 or 60 mA per segment)

It appears to work correctly, but are there any long term issues with running a constant current strip with a constant voltage supply, as long as the current draw (maximum current available by driver is less than the combined segment maximums) and voltage are within range for the strip?

Is there an issue with the PWM function on the constant current strip?

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheets for the driver and strip.

Comment: Power wastage springs to mind. What does this mean (i.e. what is it): *constant voltage strip*??

Comment: The Driver is this one: https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=HLG-240H

Comment: The dimming interface is this https://nanoltg.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/nanometer_dm4_v2.pdf

and the strip is a constant current LED strip 66 segments long 40/50 or 60mA each (44-48v)

Comment: @GarethSmith Use @ sign to mention users so they get notified about your comment.

Comment: Note that R goes down as temp goes up, which means I goes up with temp as well. As long as the voltage provided cannot produce more amps when hot than spec, it will be fine. In short, If things are stable after warming up, it's fine, until you change a leg of the 3-leg ohm's law stool. To wit, if your LED wants 50ma, and your voltage happens to provide 45-55ma over temp range, there's no significant diff between a CC and CV supply; they both produce the same result.

Comment: This dimming interface is multichannel, are you using one channel or several channels?

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, this is what I thought. My concern is that the additional current is available in the driver, it's just being reduced by the PWM interface to prevent thermal runaway etc. But every PWM cycle, will additional stress be inflicted on the strip for any reason?

Comment: @bobflux Just one channel

Comment: @GarethSmith: no PWM can only add longevity to the LEDs by reducing heat, they don't mind the "blinking" at all. at all.

Answer (score 0):

You typically would not use a CV/CC supply for this DMX board.
I would use the Meanwell LRS series CV supply. 
If it works, everything is okay as the Meanwell's output will not exceed 48V.

---

[image]

> So you are saying that the constant current strip will run from a CV
> supply?

The CV power is connected to the V+ and V- terminals. 
It is my strong assumption that the DMX device has the CC circuitry.

---

> Will dimming by PWM reduce the current within range so that it is not
> damaged?

The current is determined by the DIM+ and DIM- terminals.
You must never allow the DIM voltage exceed the max current of the strip.

I am not familiar with this DMX device so I cannot give you assurances that it will not burn your strip.  Also I know nothing about the strip.  It does seem particular to me that a strip would use only 40-60 mA.
Using a 5 amp driver seems a little mismatched.

If you are only looking to dim the strip you may want to eliminate the DMX device.
You need to describe your application better.  
Post more info about the LED strips and what you want to do with them.
Why are you using a DMX device?
How many strips?
DMX is typically used for complex stage lighting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you are saying that the constant current strip will run from a CV supply? Will dimming by PWM reduce the current within range so that it is not damaged?

Comment: @GarethSmith added to my response.